# using same datatype in boost variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

Can we explicitly typecast the value which is to be stored in boost varaint??

Example:

```
typedef int abc;

typedef int asd;

typedef boost::variant<abc, char, asd, float> link_try1;

int main()
{

  link_try1 qw;
  qw = static_cast<asd>(1234);
  printf("value of which is:%d", qw.which());
  return 0;
}
```

Here I want the which() function to retrun 3 but it always retruns 0.
Is there a way of directly changing the value in which_ (private variable in class variant) or explicitly specifying the datatype to be used??

Regards
Ankith

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but it won't work as expected.

The key idea, on a variant, is that the type acts as a *key*. When you actually request a given type (using `boost::get` or visitation), the first type in the `variant` that matches the key is elected, thus here `asd` would be haughtily ignored.

If you need to store several integers for different purposes, you can use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` to create different integer-like classes and use those in the `variant`.